# Timeline for v2.0 of the API?

Tags: discussion

Since v1.0 is now finalized, I thought I'd inquire about v2.0.

I'm guessing it will be a few weeks before you even start planning it.

Can you give us a long term estimate of when the private beta for v2.0 will begin? 6 months...? A year...?

*P.S. If it's even half as good as v1.0, we're in for a treat!*

Answer (score 5):

**We don't know**<sup>*</sup>

I suspect - despite our, and the communities, best efforts - there will be some hack-ish workarounds for defects in v1.0.  Part of v2.0 would be addressing these issues, and we need some time to pass for them to become obvious.

Another part of v2.0 would be bringing the API into line with the improvements made on the sites.  The longer we wait, the more we can knock out in one go.  Of course, the longer we wait the longer [app]s don't have access to things displayed on the sites.  Something of a balancing act there.

Finally, since we've implied - though not quite promised - write access in v2.0 the exact mechanisms for *that* need to be worked out.  This implies significant UI changes, in addition to some serious platform work.  The price of failure with regards to security is also very high.  A lot of internal work will have to be done to even make v2.0 possible before we start bringing in the community to work on the public aspects.

<sub>*Credits: [lfoust](https://stackapps.com/users/11/lfoust)</sub>

Comment: So 6-8 weeks then?

Comment: @george is just as impatient as I am.  Except he wants version 2.0, while I want my iPhone 4 to arrive.

Comment: +2 - 1 for the credits and 1 for the hack-ish workarounds ;) I share your concern regarding *price of failure with regards to security*, a tough job and responsibility I wouldn't be too keen facing myself, so good luck with this! That said, have you considered a more agile approach of progressive improvement instead already to break that tie? I can see how this is a problem with your committal to supporting two API versions at a time, which implies some (necessary) stability, but maybe an 'unstable' approach for the next version could help here regardless (can't believe I just wrote that ...)?

Comment: No hurry... just wondered if you had a ballpark figure.

Comment: I think you guys will do a great job.  I do believe that despite your initial problems with a successful business model for private StackExchange, with a write API businesses would pay top dollar for StackExchange.  Being able to integrate it into your enterprise application would be huge.  I know we've looked at a number of options for private community Q&A and nothing compares to StackExchange, we were disappointed when you made the changes, but we still would have needed a write API before implementing it in our software.  So I do hope you include write-access in V2 and I wish you luck!

Answer (score 4):

I am almost positive the answer to this question is **"We don't know"**. Why would they be in any hurry to start on the next version when the first version has only been released for a couple of hours? I would be surprised if they could give you an answer to this question in the next 6 months.

Comment: Well if v1.0 is finalized, at least all they have to do for the next little while is monitor the stuff to make sure it's working.